# Can I programmatically control the account number when creating a new account in MetaTrader 4?

Tags: forex, metatrader4

I have a C++ plug-in for MetaTrader 4 that allows me to create new accounts in it for trading purposes. I would like to be able to dictate to MT4 the account number when creating the new account. Might any one know whether this is possible and how it might be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the account number in the login field of the UserRecord struct your are using in the call to UserRecordNew method. If the account already exits you will get an error from the method as apposed to RET_Ok.

Answer (score 2):

The account number is generated by the broker upon account creation - So the simple answer is No; you cannot control it. The only way would be to generate an account number, and based on it anticipate what the next account number will be. This is only possible if the account number algorithm is broker-specific. This would surprise me though. I am willing to bet that account numbers are generated by MetaQuotes server with a one-way-function.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate, please see answer blow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any API, you can manually enter the account number. If the specified account number exists, the system will reject your request. Is there any particular reason you want to enter custom numbers while opening the account?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to control the account number. The justification of this is the fact that the account number is developed by the broker upon the opening of an account.The only way that this would be possible would be if one was to generate an account number and use this number to anticipate what the next account number will be. This approach is however, possible if the account number algorithm is broker-specific.